# Using XPATHs from file and adding relevant attribute

Tags: xslt, dynamic, xpath, attributes

May be my XSL approach is wrong? please correct me the way to handle this situation

I want to grab XPATHs and Attrs from a mapping file, then use XPATH to match, and apply attributes to XML.

Here is my 3 inputs files:

**mappings.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mappings>
    <map xpath="//title" class="title" others="moreToCome" />
    <map xpath="//subtitle" class="subtitle" others="moreToCome" />
    <map xpath="//p" class="p" others="moreToCome" />
</mappings>
```

**Source.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <title>title text</title>
    <subtitle>subtitle text</subtitle>
    <p>subtitle text</p>
</root>
```

**StyleMapping.xsl**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:param name="fMappings" select="document('mappings.xml')" />
<xsl:variable name="xpath"><xsl:text>justToMakeItGlobal</xsl:text></xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
  </xsl:copy>
  <!-- loop thru map in mappings.xml -->
  <xsl:for-each select="$fMappings//mappings/map">
    <xsl:call-template name="dyn">
      <xsl:with-param name="xpath" select="@xpath" />
      <xsl:with-param name="class" select="@class" />
      <xsl:with-param name="others" select="@others" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="$xpath" mode="dyn">
  <xsl:param name="xpath"/>
  <xsl:param name="class"/>
  <xsl:param name="others"/>
  <xsl:attribute name="class"><xsl:value-of select="$class" /></xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:attribute name="others"><xsl:value-of select="$others" /></xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is what is planning to do, but i'm not getting the correct way of doing it in XSLT:
1. Read mappings.xml file
2. Loop thru each map tag
3. grab xpath and attr's
4. apply template match/select with above xpath
5. add attr's to above selected nodes

**output.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <title class="title" others="moreToCome">title text</title>
    <subtitle class="subtitle" others="moreToCome">subtitle text</subtitle>
    <p class="p" others="moreToCome">subtitle text</p>
</root>
```

Comment: Note also that you are calling a template named "dyn" - but no such template exists (your template has *mode* but no *name*).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can have a template with a calculated match pattern. Let me suggest a different approach:

**mappings.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mappings>
    <map elem="title" class="Title" others="moreToCome1" />
    <map elem="subtitle" class="Subtitle" others="moreToCome2" />
    <map elem="p" class="P" others="moreToCome3" />
</mappings>
```

**stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="mappings" select="document('mappings.xml')/mappings" />

<xsl:template match="*">
<xsl:variable name="elem" select="name()" />
<xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <xsl:if test="$elem = $mappings/map/@elem">
        <xsl:attribute name="class">
            <xsl:value-of select="$mappings/map[@elem=$elem]/@class"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="others">
            <xsl:value-of select="$mappings/map[@elem=$elem]/@others"/>
        </xsl:attribute>    
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Testing with the following source XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <title original="yes">title text</title>
    <subtitle>subtitle text</subtitle>
    <p>para text</p>
    <nomatch attr="test">another text</nomatch>
</root>
```

results in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <title original="yes" class="Title" others="moreToCome1">title text</title>
    <subtitle class="Subtitle" others="moreToCome2">subtitle text</subtitle>
    <p class="P" others="moreToCome3">para text</p>
    <nomatch attr="test">another text</nomatch>
</root>
```

Comment: Thanks, could understand what you mean, but going this way will not fully solve complex nested mappings, like with this one:  
    <map xpath="\\p" class="p"/>  
    <map xpath="\\box\p" class="box-body"/>
    <map xpath="\\notes\p" class="notes-body"/>
    <map xpath="\\table\tgroup\row\entry\p" class="tab-body"/>
Here the class with change respective of xpath. If this mapping logic couldn't be applied in XSLT, then I should think of PERL. Please let me know your suggestion?

Comment: @Shiv 1. Please do not post code in comments; edit your question instead. 2. Perhaps you could write your mappings in the form of templates - then include/import these in your stylesheet?